# How to reset values in for loop in swift 2

Tags: for-loop, dictionary, while-loop, swift2, enumerate

I'm having trouble with the following line of code:

```
var participants = [String]()
var dict = [String: String]()

func createDictionary() {

    var hat = participants
    var loopCount = 0

    for (keyIndex, key) in hat.enumerate() {

        var valueIndex: Int {
            var index: Int
            repeat {
                index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hat.count)))
                loopCount++
                print(loopCount)
                if loopCount > participants.count + 1000 {
                    createDictionary()
                }
            } while index == keyIndex || dict.values.contains(hat[index])
            return index
        }
        dict[key] = hat[valueIndex]
    }

}
```

My goal is for "dict" to contain a dictionary created from "participants".  This function will work most of the time, but will sometimes enter into an infinite loop.  I was trying to make it so that if it loops more than 1000 times or so, that the function would repeat and try again.

I think the problem is that I can't reset the values for "keyIndex" and "key" because those are "let constants".  But I'm not sure.

Is there a way to reset the loop so those values?  Or have the entire function retry?

Comment: You actually **can** change the values if you explicitly `var` the variables you want: `for (var keyIndex, var key) in hat.enumerate()`. Although that should be needed very rarely and is not always the best way to do things. If your function enters an infinite loop maybe it's best to review and try a different logic, maybe from another point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if anyone is interested, I was able to figure it out.  I'm still new to this, so I'm sure others would have been able to figure it out quicker :)

Anyway, I updated the code as follows:

```
var participants = [String]()
var dict = [String: String]()

func createDictionary() {

    var hat = participants
    var drawName = [String: String]()
    var loopCount = 0


    for (keyIndex, key) in hat.enumerate() {

        var valueIndex: Int {
            var index: Int
            repeat {
                loopCount++
                index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hat.count)))
            } while index == keyIndex || drawName.values.contains(hat[index]) && loopCount < hat.count + 50

            return index
        }

        drawName[key] = hat[valueIndex]

    }

    if loopCount > hat.count + 30 {
        self.createDictionary()
    } else {
        dict = drawName
    }

}
```

mathielo was right that I was most likely looking at this the wrong way.  Basically I just instructed the loop to not loop too many times, then recalled the function if it had to try too many times to get a value.  The above code works without freezing the program.

Comment: Did just now :)  I tried doing it right away, but it wouldn't let me.  Thanks for the reminder :)